# Why does Touchegg's CPU usage increase over time?

Tags: linux, touchpad, cpu-usage

I'm using [Touchégg](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/) on Arch Linux and it functions splendidly. However, I'm noticing that as I use it, it gradually takes more and more CPU time.

There are a few things to note:

- If I kill the process and start it again, then the CPU Usage drops to normal levels (0.1%).

  - I'm starting the process from `xfce4-appfinder` to execute the command, `touchegg`.
- The `touchegg` command is being run at session startup with [these settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1U71.png) in `xfce4-session-settings`.

I have a few suspicions:

- It's possible that my problem is that I should include some argument when I start `touchegg`. I'm currently starting it without any arguments.

  - Notably, running it in a terminal makes it function, but also gives a *lot* of output whenever I perform a gesture.
  - Also notably, I'm unable to find any information about actually starting Touchegg when I search for it.
- It seems to only increase in CPU usage as I actually use gestures. Using a USB mouse, or just leaving the computer idle don't *seem* to increase the process's CPU time (However, this may not actually be the case; I haven't had a chance to rigorously confirm this).

Here's some miscellaneous information, in case it may be useful:

- Linux Distribution: Arch Linux
- Linux Kernel: 3.13.5-1

Does anyone know what I can do to keep its CPU usage low so I don't need to kill/start the process every so often?

Comment: maybe you could use a crontab to periodically kill and start the process for you?

Comment: Sounds like complicated issue. You should file a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/issues/list).

Comment: @DanielQue I've tried that, but for some reason the process doesn't start properly no matter how I build the script run by crond (or by starting `touchegg` directly by cron).

Comment: @user19087 that's one way to go. However, it doesn't seem to have been updated in over a year.

Comment: I rather think it is a programming bug. If you wish to attack this problem yourself, first run `strace -c` and `ltrace -c`. If nothing is out of the ordinary then the bug is internal to Touchegg and not related to the system. In that case you must use a profiler like gprof or callgrind. Google is full of useful tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be the issue with X, I came across this before using the touchegg but gave up on it pretty quickly. Run it until cpu will start going high and look in your `journalctl` you should see X related warning/error messages. As well as @user19087 offered `strace -c` would be a good way to start looking deeper into the issue.

Did you build touchegg from AUR or yourself?

Comment: From the AUR. Both `touchegg` and `touchegg-git` have the problem. At this point, I just have a script running that kills it and restarts it every 10 minutes.

Comment: That's a rather ugly work around yeah...
The last mentions that I can find of people having the same issue were back from 2011 and i don't think there were newer releases of touchegg. It's rather outdated now

Comment: Indeed, it is super hackish. It works though, and is stable. I wonder if there are any alternatives to touchegg for 3+ finger gestures. Seems like a question for [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I use arch myself with lenovo clickpad and well configured synaptic for touch gestures, but yes that's all 3 fingers max. I have searched before and the only other thing I've seen is a combination of `ginn` and ported `utouch` from Ubuntu. I don't know any other alternatives, but do post them back if you find some!